# JSP java2d JSP 2d Taglib - Rhino gives me an error

Tags: jsp, rhino, taglib

I'm trying to draw simple 2d things in my JSP application. I found this taglib on http://ditchnet.org/2d/ but it doesn't work as expected...
If I start my webapp I get the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at 
>   line 20
>
> 17:     
>   18:
>
> ## Hello World!
>
> 19:         
>   20:             
>   21:
>   22:                 // create red gradient paint
>   23:                 var color1 = new java.awt.Color(0xC80021);
>
> Stacktrace:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Rhino encountered an error 
>   while evaluating the JavaScript in the  tag with id 'polygon': null

So it says my tag with polygon is null. But it's not as you all can see...
Anybody with a good idea? :)
Or maybe another solution for drawing 2d stuff in jsp?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't gave my root directory the needed rights so it couldn't work well...
Now it's allowed to write and it works like hell ;)
Great Taglib btw.

Greetings,

Matthias